How large can $\| x \|_2$ be if $\|x\|_1 = 1, x \geq 0$, and $Fx$ is constant on $n/2$ components?
Let $A \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ be generated by picking each integer with probability $1/2$.
We define the (cosine) Fourier transform matrix with $F_{jk} = \cos(jk/n)$.
Among all probability distributions on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ (vectors $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with each $x_i\geq 0$ such that $\sum_i x_i = 1$) such that $Fx$ equals $-1$ on $A$, how large can $\|x\|_2$ be (on average, or with high probability, etc.) ?
I am expecting $x$ to be spread out (thus $\|x\|_2$ to be small), because if $x$ were large on a single coordinate, $Fx$ could not be constant on a (random) set of size $n/2$.. but I can't find quantitative results. Any ideas ?
